# React.js: Dynamically create complex DOM from nested JSON before rendering

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Recently I am trying to solve a problem where I have to render a document tree menu (hierarchical) from a nested JSON coming from a request call.

**Say my JSON looks like this**

```
[{
    "title": "Food",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [{
        "title": "Veg",
        "path": "/root/Food",
        "children": [{
            "title": "Carrot",
            "path": "/root/Food/Veg",
            "children": [{
                "title": "Ooty carrot",
                "path": "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "title": "Cloths",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [{
        "title": "T shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "title": "Shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
    }]
}]
```

**I have to create the following DOM from the above JSON**

[image]

## SOLVED through jQuery:

I have the function ready to convert the JSON to DOM: in normal jQuery I would do something like the following:

```
$(function(){
    function get_tree(tree_data){
      dom += '<ul>';
      for(var i in tree_data){
        if(tree_data[i].children.length > 0){
          dom += '<li>';
          dom += '<a href="#" class="tree-parent-anchor">'+tree_data[i].title+'</a>';
          get_tree(tree_data[i].children);
          dom += '<li>';
        }
        else{
          dom += '<li>'+tree_data[i].title+'</li>'
        }
      }
      dom+= '</ul>'
    }
    var tree_data = JSON.parse($('pre').text());
    var dom= '<ul id="Menu-list">';
            get_tree(tree_data);
        dom+= '</ul>'
    $('div').append(dom);
})
```

## In REACT.JS I tried this (ofcrse it doesn't works):

```
export default class DocTree extends Component{
    state = {treeData: [{
            "title": "Food",
            "path": "/root",
            "children": [{
                "title": "Veg",
                "path": "/root/Food",
                "children": [{
                    "title": "Carrot",
                    "path": "/root/Food/Veg",
                    "children": [{
                        "title": "Ooty carrot",
                        "path": "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }, ...
        }]
    }

    render(){
        const tree_data = this.state.treeData;
        function get_tree(tree_data, dom){
              <ul>
                for(var i in tree_data)
                    if(tree_data[i].children.length > 0)
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="tree-parent-anchor">{tree_data[i].title}</a>
                            get_tree(tree_data[i].children);
                        <li>

                    else
                        <li>{tree_data[i].title}</li>
                </ul>

        var dom = <ul id="Menu-list">
            get_tree(tree_data);
        </ul>

        return(
            <div>
                {dom}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I dont exactly how to achieve the same through React.js syntax

> Please help me with - **How do it in React.js** (am using React.js 16.2.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use for loop within JSX, and secondly you can recursively render your tree after mapping over each object

```js
const data =[{
    "title": "Food",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [{
        "title": "Veg",
        "path": "/root/Food",
        "children": [{
            "title": "Carrot",
            "path": "/root/Food/Veg",
            "children": [{
                "title": "Ooty carrot",
                "path": "/root/Food/Veg/Brinjal",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "title": "Cloths",
    "path": "/root",
    "children": [{
        "title": "T shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "title": "Shirt",
        "path": "/root/Cloths",
        "children": []
    }]
}]


const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
   return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((m, index) => {
        return (<li key={index}>
          {m.title}
          {m.children && <MyComponent data={m.children} />}
        </li>);
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
class App extends React.Component {

  
  render() {
     return <div>
        <MyComponent data={data} />
     </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood JSX.

Let consider it just like a server-side language (eg: PHP, ASP),

What you're doing is `embed HTML and JSX`, just like `embed HTML and PHP`.

**Why?**
JSX is js and a JSX element is an object under the hood.

You can run some hello world JSX on https://babeljs.io/repl/ to see how JSX was transpile into ES5 (in case of ES5 browser), you'll understand JSX.

For more detail, you should read React fundamental, especially [JSX in depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

---

Finally, this is the modification needed to work:

```
function get_tree(tree_data, dom){
  var elems = [];

  for(var i in tree_data)
    if(tree_data[i].children.length > 0)
      elems.push(<li>
          <a href="#" className="tree-parent-anchor">{tree_data[i].title}</a>
          {get_tree(tree_data[i].children)}
          </li>)
    else
      elems.push(<li>{tree_data[i].title}</li>)

  return <ul>{elems}</ul>
}
```

Btw, your code is bad in practice because you're new in React, you should consider `@Shubham Khatri` idea and follow his practice.